# Getting value from event listener in JS

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I'm trying to get the value of 'firstInput' and 'secondInput' out of the event handler in the code pasted, but console(log) produces 'undefined' when I run it. Can you help figure this out? It runs as expected (which is great), but I can't seem to get the entered input values out of the event handlers. The input value entered via the HTML as a number is what I need to do some calculations

```js
function calc(){
    // Target input's value. Goal is to get values from input
    let firstButton = document.getElementById("button1");
    let secondButton = document.getElementById("button2");
    let pOneInput, pTwoInput;

    firstButton.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
        let firstInput = document.getElementById("first-input").value;
        if (firstInput != parseInt(firstInput)){
            console.log("NAN");
            alert("Please enter a number");
        } else{
            console.log(firstInput);
            pOneInput = firstInput;
        }
    });

    secondButton.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
        let secondInput = document.getElementById("sec-input").value;
        if (secondInput != parseInt(secondInput)){
            console.log("NAN");
            alert("Please enter a number");
        } else{
            console.log(secondInput);
            pTwoInput = secondInput;
        }
    });

    // Select values from input.


    // Compare values to see which is higher
    
}
calc();
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="top-container">
            <div class="topdiv">
                <div><p id="title">GuessNTime</p></div>
                <div class="darktheme">
                    <input class="" type="checkbox" id="theme">
                    <label class="" for="theme">
                        Dark Theme
                    </label>
                    <span id="howtoplay">How to play</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="middle">
            <div id="left" class="left"></div>
            <div class="lysol">
                <div class="">
                    <div class="">
                        <div id="filter" class="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="themain">
                    <div id="count"><span id="twenty">20</span><span id="arraw">⇣</span></div>
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="gamevideo">
                            <video id="myvid" class="ourvid" muted></video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="othervideo">
                        <div id="peerDiv" class="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="gamebox">
                    <div class="gameplay">GameBox</div>
                    <div class="gameplay">ClueBox</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="right" class="right"></div> 
        </section>
        <section class="april">
            <div id="firstcol" class="bottomlayer">
                <p id="player1" class="goaway">Player One</p>
                <div id="firstformdiv" class="formdiv">
                        <input id="first-input" type="text" value="">
                        <input id="button1" type="button" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </div>
            <span id="replacediv"><div id="secondcol" class="bottomlayer" href="#modal"><p id="starpause">Start | Pause</p></div></span>
            <div id="thirdcol" class="bottomlayer">
                <p id="player2"  class="goaway">Player Two</p>
                <div id="secformdiv"  class="formdiv">
                        <input id="sec-input" type="text" value="" class="form-input">
                        <input id="button2" type="button" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="qform" class="form">
            
        </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is working as expected for me. Please add the HTML for more complete debugging help.

Answer (score 0):

Console prints with console.log(myVar) and not console(log) but you write it correctly in your code so it' okay.
You can use isNaN(var) in place of : firstInput != parseInt(firstInput)
`input.value` works.

```js
let input = document.getElementById('myInput');
// before writing in the input
consol.log(input.value) // undefined
// after writing
consol.log(input.value) // "What I write in my input"
```

So You need to console log document.getElementById("first-input") before use .value on it to verify if it's correctly getted. You should receive a html string in console like :

```js
<input ... />
```